# have you started a local ros users group?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thinking about starting a local users group. Has anybody done this? There are language specific user groups in town. Some have been successful, some not so much.

If you are involved in a language specific user group but not an ros user group what do you think would need to be different?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59421/have-you-started-a-local-ros-users-group?/) by [johnjamesmiller](https://answers.ros.org/users/1652/johnjamesmiller/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2013-03-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

One was started in Sydney. [mailing list announcement](http://code.ros.org/lurker/attach/3@20130417.040837.1e3d98f8.attach)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-04-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0